# Complexity of Max Bisection on cubic planar graphs?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, max-cut

Max Bisection problem is to partition the set of nodes into two equal size sets such that the number of crossing edges is maximum. Max Bisection is $NP$-complete on cubic graphs and also on planar graphs.

> What is the complexity of Max Bisection on cubic planar graphs? Is it $NP$-complete?

Cross posted on [mathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52583/complexity-of-max-bisection-on-cubic-planar-graphs)

Comment: By "crossing edges" do you mean the edges whose endpoints are in both sets making up the bisection?

Comment: Max Bisection is MAX CUT with additional requirement that the two node sets have the same cardinality.